# Redirect old directory to new directory in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website in which I'm changing a subdirectory name for SEO purposes:

Current: website.com/nearly-new-cars/ford-focus-975
New: website.com/used-cars/ford-focus-975

I need to redirect all requests from "nearly-new-cars" to the new "used-cars" subdirectory whilst maintaining the rest of the URL (in that case, "ford-focus-975").

Is anyone able to help me with the regular expression that I'd need to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Liam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule as your first rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/nearly-new-cars/(.+)$ /used-cars/$1
```

OR using `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^nearly-new-cars/(.+)$ /used-cars/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually found another website on our server using this:

`RedirectMatch 301 /old-dir(.*) http://www.website.com/new-dir$1?`

What is the difference between my code and yours? I've never seen the (.+) before.

Thanks again!

Comment: `/old-dir(.*)` is not a very good regex since that can also match `/old-dir123` OR just `/old-dir` whereas what I have is `/old-dir/(.+)` will only match `/old-dir/anything-here`. And `.+` means match 1 or more characters whereas `.*` means 0 or more.